# Detecting event loop "lag"

Tags: javascript, event-loop

If a browser application performs more computationally heavy, or blocking operations, then the event loop will lengthen.

Is there a way to get *qualitative* metrics regarding the length of the event loop?

This is with a view to gauging how "easily" a client-side web application is rendering on the client (i.e. whether it has sufficient computational resources to deliver a smooth, timely experience).

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into `window.requestAnimationFrame` (without actually doing any rendering) and measure the average time between invocations, based on the high-resolution timer value passed to its callback.

This would in effect just be an FPS counter.

Comment: So this would work because the callback supplied to request animation frame is guaranteed to be invoked immediately before the end of a tick? Can you expand on why this works?

Comment: AIUI, you won't get calls to the callback any more frequently than the screen refresh rate, but if the current frame has been "missed" (because the event loop was busy processing other code) then so will the callback.

Comment: Oh, and on newer browsers there's also `setImmediate` which AFAIK will force the supplied callback to be called ASAP, but from the event loop.